# Stop listening for node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal

When I do:

```
node server.js
```

Then my terminal (osx) starts to listen for messages like errors and logs from the node app.

1. How can I start node without listening?
2. How can I stop listening programtically from within node.js?

Comment: What's in `server.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash shell (the typical default on a Unix-like operating system such as OS X), you can start it up like this:

```
node server.js 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

That directs STDERR and STDOUT to `/dev/null`.

If you also want to throw the process into the background so you can do other things in the shell, add a `&` at the end:

```
node server.js 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

Just make sure you know how to bring it back to the foreground (`fg` command) and/or know how to kill it when you no longer want it running.